# JAX-RS exception with Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, tomcat

**When starting the a servlet (from eclipse), I'm getting the following error:**
It's tomcat 7 and the servlet is REST.

```
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\beezer\WebServerWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\BeezerServer\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-j2ee_1.4_spec-1.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
448 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet - com.test.AddressBookApplication<br />
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.AddressBookApplication<br />
    at
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)<br/>
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)<br/>
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)<br/>
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.getApplication(RestServlet.java:144)<br/>
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.createRequestProcessor(RestServlet.java:105)<br/>
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.init(RestServlet.java:81)<br/>
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)<br/>
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)<br/>
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)<br/>
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)<br/>
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)<br/>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)<br/>
Aug 30, 2012 7:49:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log<br/>
INFO: Marking servlet JAX-RS Servlet as unavailable<br/>
Aug 30, 2012 7:49:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup<br/>
SEVERE: Servlet /BeezerServer threw load() exception<br/>
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.test.AddressBookApplication<br/>
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.init(RestServlet.java:91)<br/>
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)<br/>
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)<br/>
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)<br/>
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)<br/>
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)<br/>
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)<br/>
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)<br/>
Aug 30, 2012 7:49:41 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

**My web.XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><br/> <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee<br/> http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>BeezerServer</display-name>
    <servlet>
      <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
      <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.AddressBookApplication</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/jaxrs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Does anyone has a clew?
thanks!

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

First check that this class really exists. Check class name and package. Does it belong to the web project or dependent project?

If everything is OK, refresh project, then run Project/Clean, then clean and re-publish tomcat. If it does not work create server again (I mean in eclipse). If it still does not work go to `C:\beezer\WebServerWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\BeezerServer\WEB-INF\classes` (the path is taken from your log) and check that the class file is there.

Good luck and welcome to the club of people that spend night fighting against the bugs in plugin of tomcat for eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `C:\beezer\WebServerWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\BeezerServer\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-j2ee_1.4_spec-1.1.jar` It  contains the class Servlet.java, which should be provided by the AS itself. If you are using Maven, mark the dependency as provided (`<scope>provided</scope>`)

Btw. the jar is still needed for compilation, but not in runtime.

*EDIT: Oh, now I've noticed, it is only INFO in the log. So it is not the source of the problem, the root cause is the `ClassNotFound` ex. Make sure the class is on the classpath.*